# Weyl orbits of integral dominant weights and convex polytopes

Tags: lie-algebras, symplectic-geometry, root-systems

Let $\xi$ be an integral dominant weight of a root system $\Delta$, and let $\mathcal{O}_{\xi}$ be its orbit under the action of the Weyl group.  The elements of the orbit are the vertices of an $n$-dimensional convex polytope.

Is there an efficient way to pick out all the subsets of points in $\mathcal{O}_{\xi}$ forming the faces of the convex polytope?

Comment: The Weyl group acts transitively on the roots $\Delta$. Why isn't $\mathcal{O_{\xi}}$ all of $\Delta$?

Comment: An interesting question (+1)! It seems to me that we can group $\xi$ with any $n-1$ neighbors gotten by applying simple reflections to it. All the faces are then in the orbit of one of those faces, but there is overcounting. Too late for me to think straight. @user43687: $\xi$ is just a dominant weight, not a root.

Comment: ah yes. I misread the question. Thanks

Comment: ... and it is complicated by the possibility of $\xi$ having a non-trivial stabilizer. For some reason I was thinking dot action first. Sorry. It's been a while :-/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That was my thought too: I want to avoid the overcounting.  I also want to avoid writing a brute force algorithm that just finds all possible subsets of vertices that lie on a plane and checks if the plane is one of the faces.

Comment: @user43687, I do not think the Weyl group acts transitively on the roots of a general root system. It acts transitively if the root system is irreducible, but I do not think it holds in general.